# Error: on cron (field_purge_batch)

Tags: cron, 9, entities

Seems that Drupal got issues removing deleted fields on cron (just a theory).

Got the following error message after cron ran. Anybody got an idea how to get rid of it?

```
Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, bool given in field_purge_batch() (line 96 of /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/modules/field/field.purge.inc)
#0 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc(347): _drupal_error_handler_real(2, 'foreach() argum...', '/Users/captainEvil', 96)
#1 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/modules/field/field.purge.inc(96): _drupal_error_handler(2, 'foreach() argum...', '/Users/captainEvil', 96)
#2 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/modules/field/field.module(169): field_purge_batch(50)
#3 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cron.php(249): field_cron()
#4 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleHandler.php(405): Drupal\Core\Cron->Drupal\Core\{closure}(Object(Closure), 'field')
#5 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cron.php(257): Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAllWith('cron', Object(Closure))
#6 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cron.php(136): Drupal\Core\Cron->invokeCronHandlers()
#7 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Cron.php(75): Drupal\Core\Cron->run()
#8 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/modules/system/src/CronController.php(59): Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Cron->run()
#9 [internal function]: Drupal\system\CronController->runManually()
#10 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(564): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
#12 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(124): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure))
#13 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array)
#14 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(158): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
#15 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(80): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
#16 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/modules/contrib/simple_oauth/src/HttpMiddleware/BasicAuthSwap.php(67): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#17 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(58): Drupal\simple_oauth\HttpMiddleware\BasicAuthSwap->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#18 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(48): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#19 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(106): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#20 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(85): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#21 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/vendor/asm89/stack-cors/src/Asm89/Stack/Cors.php(49): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#22 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(48): Asm89\Stack\Cors->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#23 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(51): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#24 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#25 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/bq/bq-be/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(709): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#26 /Users/captainEvil/WORK/WORKSPACE/valet/BQ/bq-be/web/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#27 /Users/captainEvil/.composer/vendor/weprovide/valet-plus/server.php(131): require('/Users/captainEvil')
#28 {main}
```

Comment: This is only a warning and most likely there are no fields to delete, otherwise there would be data in an array. Did you manipulate the deleted fields in the database? Normally the foreach() loop would receive an empty array and not a boolean if there are no fields to delete.

Comment: fyi: the field_storage_unique_id is null. No I did not. But I got an idea. I installed a currency module which had thrown heavy error on uninstall. I wonder if I could somehow identify the source of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is caused by the database value `field.storage.deleted` (collection `state`) in the table `key_value`.

If there are no fields to delete it should contain a serialized empty array:

```
a:0:{}
```

An empty value is also OK, but it must not contain a boolean as placeholder for an empty array.

Comment: I cannot prove it. To ensure no more hidden database issues I reinstalled the site and reimported the configuration as the content is just for testing so far. The answer might be important for others. Thanks